# Add links to flexslider images

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, flexslider

I'm working with a wordpress site and I'm wondering if there is a way to add a link to each flexslider image so that when clicked the link will take the user to a different page within the site?
I have been searching for answers for hours with no luck. This is the code,

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Home
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div class="content">
<?php $slides = carbon_get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slides', 'complex');
        if($slides) : ?>
            <div class="main-slider flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
            <?php foreach($slides as $slide) :
                if(empty($slide['image'])) {
                continue;
                } ?>
            <li><img src="<?php echo assante_get_thumb_url($slide['image'], 690, 461); ?>" alt="" /></li>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>   
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap an image in a link. Like this:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <a href='linkto'><img src="slide1.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
</div>
```

In the [main page](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) there is an example (second image).

**EDIT**:

```
//Let's say you have this array:
<?php 
    $slides = array(
        array('image' => 'slide1.jpg','link' => 'link1'), 
        array('image' => 'slide2.jpg','link' => 'link2')
    );
?>

<ul class="slides">
    <?php
    foreach ($slides as $slide) :
        if (empty($slide['image'])) {
            continue;
        }
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $slide['link']?>"> //Now we have a 'link' key to match every slide.
                <img src="<?php echo assante_get_thumb_url($slide['image'], 690, 461); ?>" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This allowed me to give all of the images the same link but as far as I can tell none of the images have an id, so I'm wondering how I would give each one a different link.

Comment: @MariahJadeCole. As I can see, you have an array with all the slide images. You can set an index to store every link as well. I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: I'm glad @mjadecole, I'd never leave a princess in distress ;)